# Camel-Netty4 Unsupported message type InputStreamCache Error

Tags: apache-camel, netty

We are exploring using Camel and Netty4 to setup routes between a device that uses TCP sockets to stream XML Messages to our server.  The process follows the path of:

IncomingXML -> transform to POJO -> process(create response) -> transform(response to XML) -> return XML Response.

The routes are defined an a Blueprint XML file:

```
<camelContext id="Lucy" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <dataFormats>
        <jaxb id="pojos" contextPath="custom.pojo"/>
    </dataFormats>
    <route streamCache="true">
        <from uri="netty4:tcp://0.0.0.0:9000?serverInitializerFactory=#spf&amp;sync=true"/>
        <unmarshal ref="pojos"/>
        <process ref="pojosProcessor"/>
        <marshal ref="pojos"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

We setup our pipeline with the following ServerInitializerFactory initChannel.

```
@Override
protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
    ch.pipeline().addLast(new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN, 66560, 0, 4, 0, 4, true));
    ch.pipeline().addLast(new XmlFrameDecoder(66560));
    ch.pipeline().addLast(new LengthFieldPrepender(4));
    ch.pipeline().addLast(new ByteArrayEncoder());
    ch.pipeline().addLast(new ServerChannelHandler(consumer));

}
```

The pojoProcessor is creating the response and adding it to the Echange in the as the body of the Out object.

Everything is working up until we send the response back. Because the client requires the length be pre-appended to the message, we thought the right encoders to use would be

```
ch.pipeline().addLast(new LengthFieldPrepender(4));
ch.pipeline().addLast(new ByteArrayEncoder());
```

But with this chain after we perform the marshal we get the following error in the logs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: unsupported message type: InputStreamCache (expected: ByteBuf, FileRegion)
```

We are at a loss as to what the proper encoder chain should be. Do we need to implement a custom codec, or is there a solution with the supplied codecs?

Any help, direction or examples that anyone has would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: and if you set streamCache="false"

Answer (score 0):

Convert the payload to a `byte[]` which is something camel-netty understands.

```
<route streamCache="true">
    <from uri="netty4:tcp://0.0.0.0:9000?serverInitializerFactory=#spf&amp;sync=true"/>
    <unmarshal ref="pojos"/>
    <process ref="pojosProcessor"/>
    <marshal ref="pojos"/>
    <convertBodyTo type="byte[]"/>
</route>
```

Comment: I added the suggestion by Claus and it is now working but I am now seeing the following message...

Comment: 63 - org.apache.camel.camel-netty4 - 2.18.0 | Closing channel as an exception was thrown from Netty. Caused by: [java.io.IOException - Connection reset by peer]
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer